# Appium entering text twice in fields on IPad

Tags: java, appium, appium-ios

I'm new to appium and trying to automate a native app for IPad. The issue that I'm getting is when I'm trying to enter text in fields, it is getting entered twice. for e.g., if I want to enter `abcd` in a text field, the output that I get is `abcdabcd`.

Here is the snippet from my code:

```
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("emailFieldLogin").setValue(email);
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("passwordLogin").setValue(password);
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("doneButtonLogin").click();

/*
   jave-client -> 7.0.0
   Appium      -> 1.15.1
*/
```

I've also tried using `sendKeys` and `Action` class but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for others, Issue was resolved after updating appium to 1.17.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys("");
```

Comment: Please add an [explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers).

Comment: Once you tap on an edit-text filed default keyboard opens, appium driver uses the keyboard to enter values in the filed